# FRAGSTATS Problem with "User Defined Tiles"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, fragstats

I have had recurring problems using FRAGSTATS 4.2.1 when trying to calculate four land cover classes over a large area using census tracts as the user-defined tiles. I have made sure the two layers I am using (land cover and census tracts, both converted to raster format) are identical in ArcGIS (e.g. column/row, uncompressed size, format (geoTIFF), pixel type, and pixel depth) and still have no success.

After running FRAGSTATS, it says "Error: Data buffering failure (level 2)" and "Analysis failed for file: tile_****" which that tile number is the Object_ID for the northernmost census tract in the study area. However, the output gives all of the patch, class, and landscape statistics for that "failed tile" and I have confirmed this by adding the "AREA" output column from the FRAGSTATS output and comparing it to the total area of the census tract in ArcGIS. So, why is it failing for that specific tile and only giving me the output for that tile, and why is it not giving me the output for my entire study area?